# Wishing Someone a Happy Birthday

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, imperatives

Is it correct to say "Please wish John a very happy birthday from me"? Or should it be "Please wish John a very happy birthday for me"?

Comment: Correct by what standards? In everyday usage either is OK, but if one wanted to be really, really pedantic, one could argue that neither is correct because, when talking to John, the person would only be transmitting, conveying the wishes.